# Dependent crosstalk filters in R flexdashboard

Tags: r, flexdashboard, crosstalk

I have created a reactable with crosstalk filters in Flexdashboard. Is there a way to establish a dependency between the two filters without including shiny?

---

### title: "test"
output:
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(crosstalk)
library(reactable)
```

### Column {data-width=650}

## Chart A

### Row

```
Mydata<- data.frame(Animal=c("cat","lyon","dog","cat","cat","mouse","dog"),ID=c("A","B","C","A","A","D","C"))

sharedata<-SharedData$new(Mydata)

reactable(sharedata)
```

### Sidebar {.sidebar data-width="250"}

```
filter_select("animal", "Animal", sharedata, group=~Animal)

filter_select("ID", "ID", sharedata, group=~ID)
```